# Using Autoencoder on numerical dataset in Keras

Tags: dataset, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to develop an Intrusion Detection System based on deep learning using Keras.

We simulated a NORMAL network traffic and I prepared it in CSV file (numerical dataset of network packets fields (IP source, port,etc..)). But I do not have the ABNORMAL (malicious) packets to train the neural network on.

I searched for problems like that and I found that Autoencoder is a good approach in unsupervised learning, but the thing is that I am new to deep learning, and I only found this example https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html where they are using Autoencoder on images dataset.

I want to use Autoencoder (or any thing useful in my case) with numerical CSV dataset in order to predict if the incoming packet is normal or malicious.

Any recommendation?

Comment: What recommendations do you want?  Images are numerical data, so the example link you provide is relevant.   This [blog post](http://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/12/10/variational-autoencoder/) might get you on the right course.  Be aware that is pre-dates Keras 2.

Comment: The link I provided above mentions in its first few lines of code the term of 'encoding_dim', what is encoding dimension and how can I calculate the proper encoding dim of my dataset? @DanHinckley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:

You can load the numerical dataset into python using e.g. [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) load text. Then, specify the encoder and decoder networks (basically just use the Keras Layers modules to design neural networks). Make sure the input layer of the encoder accepts your data, and the output layer of the decoder has the same dimension. Then, specify appropriate loss function (least squares, cross entropy, etc’) again with Keras losses. Finally, specify your optimizer with (surprise!) Keras optimizers.

Thats it, your done! Hit ‘run’, and watch your autoencoder autoencode (because that is how the autoencoders do). If you want a great tutorial about how to construct this.

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.layers import Input,Dense
from keras.models import Model

# number of neurons in the encoding hidden layer
encoding_dim = 5
# input placeholder
input_data = Input(shape=(6,)) # 6 is the number of features/columns
# encoder is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation ='relu')(input_data)
# decoder is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(6, activation ='sigmoid')(encoded) # 6 again number of features and should match input_data


# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoded)




# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input_data, encoded)
# model optimizer and loss
autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoded)

# loss function and optimizer
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)


# train the model
autoencoder.fit(x_train,
                x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True)

autoencoder.summary()

# predict after training
# note that we take them from the *test* set
encoded_data = encoder.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Please when you post code in an answer, make sure to textually explain the content of that code, why and how it works, why and how it solves OP's question.

Comment: oh I could not comment to the OPs answer with code, so just as an addendum I wanted to add this to anyone who is trying to figure how to use numeric data for autoencoders.

Comment: was just pointing out, code-only answers aren't well seen around here. Welcome to SO btw!

Comment: This answer helped me, so thanks for the code snippet.